# In CSS, display inline-block is acting like display block

Tags: css

What I want to have is two divs side-by-side and within one of them is an image and in the other is two divs, one above the other.

This happens to be a Wordpress theme, but I'm pretty sure this is basic CSS question. 
The Wordpress stack exchange told me it was off-topic.

Call the left div #divL and the right div #divR.

I found an answer on SO mentioning that I should set `display` of `#divL` and `#divR` to
`inline-block`. I can get this to work on a test html file that I created in isolation but it doesn't work in the wordpress header. Specifically the divs in the wordpress header `#divL` and `#divR` act as if they had `display: block` rather than being positioned side-by-side.

Changing them to `display: inline` does put them side-by-side but then it
doesn't work to stack two divs within `#divR`.

I'll replicate here some of the code in the Wordpress header. Note that I'm going to simplify this by omitting the stacked divs inside `#divR`, because the symptom is obvious without that.

the following is what I'm using to try to get `#divL` and `#divR` to display side-by-side.

```css
#divL { display: inline-block; }
#divR { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="title-area">
          <div id="divL">
            <img id="logo-img" class="attachment-full size-full">
          </div>
          <div id="divR">Some text that should go on right</div>
        </div>  
        <nav> .... </nav>
      </div>
</header>
```

But they display one above the other.

Note that this actually does work to get them side-by-side, but then the
stacked divs inside `#divR` don't work as intended:

```css
  #divL { display: inline; }
  #divR { display: inline; }
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="title-area">
        <div id="divL">
          <img id="logo-img" class="attachment-full size-full">
        </div>
        <div id="divR">Some text that should go on right</div>
      </div>  
      <nav> .... </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

There is a lot of CSS on these other elements but I'm not sure which of it is important to this question so I'll wait for someone to comment and tell me what I should include.

Comment: did you set a width for these two inline-block DIVs? (i.e. less than 50%)

Comment: Most likely the divs are working as intended by the CSS, but a property value is missing or probably set by another rule

Comment: `inline-block` does not "auto size" you need to specify the width. You may also want to investigate `flex`, `css grids` and `css tables` (**NOT** html tables) to see if any of those options fit your needs better.

Comment: @JonP is there a tutorial on CSS layout that might help me? I'm an experienced programmer and I can handle complex ideas, but I don't have much HTML/CSS experience. I'd like to go through all the layout options and possibilities in moderate depth especially covering things that are a little more complex and less obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, you should set `width`s for those ìnline-blocks, that should basically do what you are after.

But as an alternative you can also use `display: flex;` on the container DIV. This can be done rather simple, but in the snippet below I added some additional settings to define a certain width for the two DIVs and to center the contents in these DIVs both horizontally and vertically (by also making the child elements flexboxes with `flex-directon: column`. For the rest of the settings see the code below.

```css
.title-area {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.title-area>* {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="title-area">
      <div id="divL">
        <img id="logo-img" src="https://placehold.it/200x150/fa0" class="attachment-full size-full">
      </div>
      <div id="divR">Some text that should go on right</div>
    </div>
    <nav> .... </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what would work:

```
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="title-area">
      <div id="divL">
        <img id="logo-img" class="attachment-full size-full" />
      </div>
      <div id="divR">
        <div id="divTR">Some text that should go on top right</div>
        <div id="divBR">Some text that should go on bottom right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav>....</nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

And the CSS:

```
#divL {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}

#divR {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
```

But also Jon P is right; it might be worth your while to investigate one of the newer methods for dynamically spacing and sizing content.